# Twitter API - Get WOEID specific trend words using Jquery and Json?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to get a list of trending topics from a specific country (Ireland) using Jquery.
When I run the following its works fine:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url:'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?callback=?',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data.trends, function(i){
            console.log(data.trends);
         });
    } });
 });
</script>
```

But when I use the Irish WOEID (23424803) in place of 'current' i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Does anyone have any idea why it works for 'current' and not the WOEID?

thanks in advance

Comment: what `WOEID` are you talking about, and what `current` .. Probably pasted the wrong code..

Comment: It's pretty clear if you read the twitter doc, though the question doesn't stand on its own (doesn't have to).  The `woeid` the OP is talking about is 23424803 and the url with that in place of `current` would just be `http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424803.json`.  I posted the solution to the problem below

Answer (score 1):

From looking at http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424803.json, the only problem you're having is that link returns a differently formatted json response.  First use jsonp, and then adapt your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424803.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data[0].trends, function(i){
                console.log(data[0].trends[i]);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Check out the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9jU/9/

Comment: no prob.  if it solved your problem, accept the answer so others can know that it's useful.